# How can I recover UV mapping before symmetrizing mesh?

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I did following steps:

1.UV expansion

2.Modified mesh, and symmetrized it by using "mesh>symmetrize"

3.Texture painting

However, because the expanded mesh in UV editing window was half due to step2, the painting was only applied to the half of the texture(see an added picture).

If I use this mesh only in Blender, there is no problem, but I want to import it to Unity, texture should be complete(not half).

I'm sorry for my poor English, but if you know hou to solve this, please tell me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could bake your current result onto a new unwrap: Go into the *Object Data* panel > *UV Maps*, create a new UV map, keep it selected, unwrap your object again, for example with the *Smart UV Project* mode, in your material create a new *Image Texture* with a new image, plug an *Input > UV Map* node and select the new UV map. Keep the new *Image Texture* selected, don't plug it for the moment, go into the *Render panel > Bake* (you need to choose Cycles, not Eevee render engine). Choose *Bake Type > Diffuse*, *Contributions > Color only*. Clik on *Bake*. Now you have a new diffuse map.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I can't understand how to do this.
Instead, I duplicate mesh, delete the left side of an original mesh and the right side of the duplicated mesh, then, using snap, I recovered previous (complete, not half) UV expansion.

Comment: You don't need to duplicate the mesh, nor delete the left side, just do a new unwrap and follow the step, you'll end up with a new image map, now you can duplicate your object in order to keep the original somewhere, then remove the first UV map that is not useful anymore, plug the new Image Texture into your Principled BSDF